# Prove that a sequence of reals together with its limit is compact by cover

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I need to prove that the set $K =\{X_n: n\in\Bbb N\}\cup \{l\} $ is compact by covers. Where  $ l=\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$. Where $X_n$ is a sequence of values in $\mathbb R$.

I understand that there are 2 cases. 
Case 1) K is countable and finite, where G = {$G_i$}$_{i\in I} $ is an arbitrary cove of K then $G^* = {G_i}_{n}$ is a finte subcover G.

I need help analyzing the other case.

Comment: The definition of $K$ is quite mysterious. What is $X_n$, first of all, and is there a missing $\cup$ or $\cap$ operator?

Comment: Is that more explicative? @ArnaudMortier

Comment: Since $G$ covers $K$, there exists $i_0$ such that $l \in G_{i_0}$. Assuming that $G$ is an open cover of $K$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon) \subseteq G_{i_0}$. What does the definition of the limit tell you about $\{ X_n \}_{n\geq1}$ for large $n$?

Comment: What kind of topology are you working on?

Comment: I see! Use `$\{ ... \}$` for the result $\{...\}$. Without backslashes the braces won't appear. If you want to size them up to whatever is inside, use `$\left\lbrace ... \right\rbrace$`.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Or just \left\{ ...\right\}

Comment: @youngsmasher That is what troubles me, because as n approaches ininity then $ X_n$ approaches l

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Nice. For some reason I thought this didn't work.

Comment: It is a good idea to make a drawing : put a dot somewhere, called $l$ and put multiple dots converging to $l$. At some point, all dots will be in a ball of a certain radius around $l$. So you only need to consider this ball and the few others for the first terms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**hint**

Assume $$K\subset \cup_{i\in I} O_i $$

then
$$\exists j\in I \;:\; l\in O_j .$$

but $$l=\lim_{n\to +\infty} X_n $$

thus $$\exists N\in\mathbb N \;:\;n> N \;\; \implies \;\;X_n\in O_j $$

and
$$K\subset (\cup_{p=0,1,2...N}O_p )\cup O_j $$

where $O_p $ is such that $$X_p\in O_p $$

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: It is Not from me